# Specifying unique content for <head> section using apache tiles

Tags: spring, jsp, apache-tiles

I'm brand new to Tiles so this is probably a very easy question.  I've created a web application using Java / Spring 3 / JSPs without the use of tiles and now I'm realizing my life would be much easier with it.

I'm a bit confused on one aspect thus far, and that's defining the layouts.  My problem is that in examples I've seen online you define a layout.jsp which contains the  information (including  tags and  tags).

My question is, the "layout.jsp" file is supposed to be the generic "one-size-fits-all" type of file, but what happens when I create another file (say welcome.jsp) which should USE the layout template, but I need to define more  and  tags...  if I define them inside of the welcome.jsp file then the rendered JSP file is not formatted correctly... i.e:

```
<head>
  <!-- This is content from the layout.jsp file -->
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     // some javascript
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This is content from the welcome.jsp file which is malformed -->
  <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my tiles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/footer.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="videos" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Videos" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/videos.jsp" />
  </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

layout.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ include file="../tracking.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>

  <link href="css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.css" media="screen" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the `tiles.xml` (as simplified as possible) and the relevant JSP elements?

Comment: @kryger okay I've added the relevant files.  So the problem I'm having is that the layout.jsp defines some <LINK> and <SCRIPT> elements, but my "videos.jsp" file will also need to have some <link> and <script> elements that only apply to that one particular file (so it wouldn't make sense to place it in the layout.jsp file).  The problem I'm likely having here is one that relates to 'best practices'

Comment: You can add js and css anywhere in your page, just remove the 'head'-tag (within the body section).

Comment: @StefanLindenberg what about <LINK> tags, are you allowed to insert those outside of <HEAD> tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new definition to change the header content:

```
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/layout.jsp">
    <!-- Defined here -->
    <put-attribute name="head" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    ...
</definition>

<definition name="videos" extends="baseLayout">
    <!-- Overridden here -->
    <put-attribute name="head" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/videos-additionalHeadDefinitions.jsp" />
    ...
</definition>
```

And add this to you layout.jsp:

```
<head>
  <!-- This is content from the layout.jsp file -->
  <title>Welcome</title>
  ...
 <tiles:insertAttribute name="head" />
</head>
```

Comment: I thought of doing this but felt like it was kind of 'hacky' solution.  Is this a best practice?