# Specifying unique <head> content in an Apache-Tiles layout

Tags: spring, jsp, apache-tiles

I'm new to Apache-Tiles.  In fact, the biggest reason I'm using it is because it is the default renderer when creating a Spring Roo application.  I know it has a big following so I figured I would give it a shot.

I am very confused, however, how to accomplish a simple task.  I'm looking to add some declarations to the `<head>` section of the page from within my layout.  I know/realize that I can create a separate jsp page for the header include and one for the body include and specify them in my views.xml file ([as pointed out in this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16512224/827480)), but this seems very clunky and not appropriate.

For example, in a specify view, I would like to include some additional JS libraries.  As well, I need to add some jQuery JS script that I want to run on the page.  By convention, I like keeping my `<body>` clear of any such code, and put all the JS in the `<head>` section.

However, the need to create 2 files for each view (a head.jsp and a body.jsp) does not seem right.  Afterall, this implies that I need to have 2 files open (head and body) as I am writing my JS jQuery code to see exactly which elements from the body are being manipulated, etc.

I know in Sitemesh I can accomplish this easily within the same page.  I also know that Sitemesh and Tiles don't purport to do the same thing, but I would have expected there to be an easier way to do this than two seperate files.

Is there no way to define different regions/includes from within the same view jsp (as in Sitemesh)?  Is the only choice to have 2 different files - one for header and one for body?  Is there nothing I can do such that I can have both  and  defns in the index.jspx page?

Current setup is:

Default.jspx:

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" >  

    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />  
    <jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8" /> 

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />    

        <util:load-scripts />

        <spring:message code="application_name" var="app_name" htmlEscape="false"/>
        <title><spring:message code="welcome_h3" arguments="${app_name}" /></title>
    </head>

    <body class="tundra spring">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" ignore="true" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" ignore="true" />   
            <div id="main">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/> 
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" ignore="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Views.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="default" name="rates/index">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/rates/index.jspx" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Index.jspx:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" 
    xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" 
    xmlns:jQWidgets="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/jQWidgets" 
    version="2.0">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <spring:message code="label_rates_index" htmlEscape="false" var="title"/>
  <util:panel id="title" title="${title}">
    <spring:message code="application_name" htmlEscape="false" var="app_name"/>
    <h3>
      <spring:message arguments="${app_name}" code="welcome_titlepane"/>
    </h3>
  </util:panel>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Tiles you are working with the composite pattern, not the decorator pattern as you were with Sitemesh.

Tiles is powerful and very flexible, you have a number options from string attributes, or list attributes to wildcards. Take a look through the Tiles documentation.

Another blog post that takes you through the more advanced capabilities of Tiles is on [tech.finn.no](http://tech.finn.no/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/)